# Convert To date Wrong format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just need to Convert my string **15/6/2014** to date, but i fail(string in wrong format) i need to set format to my Convert method before i do this, i tried this

```
EndDay = Convert.ToDateTime(strEndDayToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
EndDay = Convert.ToDateTime(strEndDay).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Not working, because  Convert want to get string like this `6/15/2014` ,but i have **15/6/2014**, sow how can i use  Convert  with string **15/6/2014**?

Comment: Your `Convert.ToDateTime` throws `FormatException`? What is your `CurrentCulture` by the way?

Comment: Try Datetime.parse ()

Comment: @EA `Convert.ToDateTime` already uses `Datetime.Parse()` explicitly..

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes you are right but before i had same problem ,but after changing it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to parse the `DateTime` using the [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
DateTime EndDay = DateTime.ParseExact(strEndDay, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: "9/6/2014"-String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. I get the same error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Try to change the date format to `d/M/yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation could be helpful in this situation. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) To my knowlege all formating on datetime objects is from string manipulation.

To get to the US date I see the example

```
// Display using current (en-us) culture's short date format
DateTime thisDate = new DateTime(2008, 3, 15);
Console.WriteLine(thisDate.ToString("d"));           // Displays 3/15/2008
```

A single "d" is for the "Short Date Format"

```
6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 6/15/2009 (en-US)
```